# Views Exposed Filter conflicting with default search

Tags: 7, search, views

When I'm on a page with an exposed filter and then go to type into the default search, clicking the search button brings me right back to the exposed filter.

For now I am hiding the search block on that page but I would like them to both be on the page.  Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you have tried so far, but Can you check if Views: Better Exposed Filters can help you with this ?

Comment: Using Better Exposed Filters does not fix the issue.